# scss variables within React webpack

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass

Apologies if this question has been asked or if there's a much better way to achieve my objective - I'm very new on the subject.

Using .scss within my React project I have a variable which is used in a number of visual elements as a highlight, eg.:

`$theme = red;
.element{
    color: $theme;
}`

I'd like the user to be able to customize this to suit their tastes within the app client, however it is compiled down by sass-loader/style-loader to something like:

`.element{
    color: red;
}`

which would require me to manually maintain a list of element classes to fire style edits at after the fact.

I am hoping that someone here knows a practical way to achieve what I'm after or, if that doesn't exist, could assist me with modifying sass-loader to also spit out a list of class names where the variable is used to a file that I can load post-compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CSS variable` instead.

Declare variables:

```
:root {
    --theme-color: red; 
}
```

... and then use it ...

```
#div1 {
    background-color: var(--theme-color); 
}

#div2 {
    background-color: var(--theme-color);
}
```

---

***Note: It does not work on Internet Explorer***
https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20variables

*Learn more about `CSS variables`*
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp

Comment: Thanks for your help, this was what I was looking for!